# Deleting file from sdcard on uninstalling app

Tags: android, qt, file, broadcastreceiver, android-sdcard

I am developing a Android app using qt with integration of Android code in that qt. using qt I am creating a file on sdcard which does not get deleted on uninstalling app. I am trying to delete that file with these two methods
 1. methiod

```
 public void deleteExternalStoragePrivateFile() {

   File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
   for(int i = 0; i< file.length; i++) {
   file[i].getAbsolutePath(); 
   Log.d("Listing files: ", file[i].getAbsolutePath());
   if (file[i].getAbsolutePath().equalsIgnoreCase("/mnt/sdcard/test.txt")) {
       file[i].delete();
       }
   }
```

}
   and calling this method in OnDestory on main activity that I do not know it correct place to invoke this method.

2 Method
In this method I am defining boradcast receiver like this

```
  public class PackageRemoval extends BroadcastReceiver 
 {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
//this.context=context;
Uri data = intent.getData();
Log.d("hi", "Action: " + intent.getAction());
Log.d("hi", "The DATA: " + data);

String action=intent.getAction();

if(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED.equalsIgnoreCase(action)){

    File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i< file.length; i++) {
    file[i].getAbsolutePath(); 
    Log.d("Listing files: ", file[i].getAbsolutePath());
    if (file[i].getAbsolutePath().equalsIgnoreCase("/mnt/sdcard/test.txt")) {
        file[i].delete();
    }
    }

}
}
}
```

I have added the receiver in Manifest file like this

```
    <receiver android:name="com.example.test.PackageRemoval">
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

but I nothing seems to work and not getting any exception or error too...any idea what I am missing ..I guess most probably I am invoking these method or broadcast receiver correctly

Answer (score 0):

When the user uninstalls your app, none of the code you wrote above will get run because the code will no longer exist.

What you should do instead is get the correct location to store your files from android.content.Context.getExternalFilesDir(). This avoids cluttering the sd card with files in random locations, and ensures that those files are cleaned up when the user uninstalls your app.

Comment: the default path is /Android/data/packageName/fileName? and Can i create file from outside Android like I am doing it with qt

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "outside Android". The code you posted above looks like Android code to me (there's an Intent, a BroadcastReceiver, a manifest), so why can't you just call Context.getExternalFilesDir() instead of hardcoding the path?

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity's `onDestroy()` does not get invoked on package uninstall. Further, by the time the PackageManager has removed your app, the `PACKAGE_REMOVED` BroadcastReceiver has already been... well.. removed.

Instead, store your files in `getExternalFilesDir()` folder, which *will* be removed on package uninstall.

Anything you place outside of that path will remain.

Comment: the default path is /Android/data/packageName/fileName i guess? and Can i create file from outside Android like I am doing it with qt

Comment: How is QT running "outside of Android"? If your code is executing within the same process, you can do anything you like with the pseudo-private external dir, and any file placed in there will be removed by PackageManager upon uninstall. As of Android 4.4, however, this directory is truly private and no other process should be able to access it.

Comment: I mean I am creating file using qtcode so not sure where I can access pseudo-private path to save it ....can you tell me what is the default path for this

Comment: Can you pass it from java into qt? The default path is as you stated above, but Android documentation strongly recommends against hardcoding default paths, as it might change between implementations.

Comment: I do think I can do it, but I am trying using this link
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#securing-application-settings-in-symbian

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can get uninstall event of your own app.

Using "inotify" in native code. For example: You can using inotify_add_watch to monitor your application's data cache folder, like /data/data/your-package-name/cache. When your application get uninstalled, you can get the folder's delete event.

Another key point is the inotify should run in a seperate process from your own application. You can invoke fork() to do this.

Once you get the uninstall event, you can delete the file on sdcard in your native code.

Answer (score -2):

Try running this code before app deletion